# Number at risk for cox regression plot

Tags: ggplot2, plot, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

can I make "number at risk "table for cox plot if I have more than one independent variable?
if it possible where can I find the relevant code (I searched  but couldn't find)
 the code I used on my data:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time,event) ~chr1q21_status+CCND1+CRTM1+IRF4,data = myeloma)

ggsurvplot(fit, data = myeloma,
  risk.table=TRUE, break.time.by=365, xlim = c(0,4000),
  risk.table.y.text=FALSE, legend.labs =  c("2","3","4+"))
```

got this message- object 'ggsurv' not found' although for only one variable and the function survfit it worked.

Comment: Have you looked at the package [`survminer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survminer/index.html)?

Comment: yes, I used that package for the KM n at risk plot but it didn't work for cox with more than one variable

Comment: Post some of the data and code you've used so far, and explain what you want to accomplish in more detail

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a comment. Also it may help to create a similar analysis using a dataset that's built-in to R so people can test your code more easily.

Answer (score 0):

> "number at risk "table for cox plot

It's not a Cox plot, it's a Kaplan-Meier plot. You're trying to plot a Cox model, when what you want is to fit KM curves using `survfit` and then to plot the resulting fit:

```r
library("survival")
library("survminer")
fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ ph.ecog + sex , data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE)
```

[image]

Since you now mention that you have continuous predictors, perhaps you could think about what you expect an at-risk table or KM plot to show.
Here's an example of binning a continuous measure (age):

```r
library("survival")
library("survminer")
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
#> Loading required package: magrittr
lung$age_bin <- cut(lung$age, quantile(lung$age))
fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ age_bin + sex , data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I tried that too before I did the cox model, it didn't work, I have 4 variables and 2 of them are continuous not sure if that is the problem

Comment: What do you expect a KM plot or at risk table for a numeric covariate to look like?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example for continuous covariates.

Comment: I know KM isn't right in this case, but I was asked to make n at risk for cox model (just the number of people who died in each period) so that was my question if I can do it? so there is no way to make a table of people who died in each period for the cox model is that right?

Comment: sorry I saw your second answer after I answered , thank you I will try that!